# How can I obtain a subset of a ListObject's HeaderRowRange?

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I'm trying to format all the cells in my ListObject's header row to the right of a certain cell, while leaving the ones to the left alone. When I started having trouble I reduced my code to this:

```
Set rpt = Me.ListObjects("Report")
With rpt.HeaderRowRange
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    .Range(.Cells(9), .Cells(12)).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
End With
```

Unfortunately, the result of this is that the entire header row is coloured red (as expected), but the sub-range that is coloured purple is 4 rows down!

[image: Excel table with Header Row red as expected, but Body Row 4 is unexpectedly purple.]

I have successfully solved the problem in the short term by taking a subrange of the ListObject's Range.

However, given that I see other questions about HeaderRowRange not working as expected (albeit in other ways), can anyone explain why HeaderRowRange.Range() behaves in this extraordinary manner?

EDIT: To be clear, I have also tried this with fully-qualified references, and obtained the same result.

Comment: So... what are you trying to do? What cells are supposed to be purple? Which specific cell is "a certain cell"?

Comment: Determined programmatically elsewhere. For the purposes of demonstration, cells 9 - 12 ought to be purple. How is it that HeaderRowRange.Range() can gave me back anything outside of the header row?

Comment: Because you've given it 9-row and 12-row offsets, respectively? Does it work if you do `.Cells(, 9)` or `.Cells(ColumnIndex:=9)` instead of providing the `RowIndex` positional parameter?

Comment: HeaderRowRange.Cells() gives me the expected cell. HeaderRowRange.Cells(9), for instance, gives me the ninth cell in the header. Notice that cells 9 - 12 are correctly highlighted purple, just not in the correct row. How did I get down there?

Comment: I've tried all kinds of different ways of specifying the range definition (A1 nomenclature, column indexes, etc.), and always get the expected columns in the wrong row.

Comment: Except it works everywhere else, see my previous comment. Cells(x) has always worked correctly for me in the past, so long as I had a single row or single column as my range. Further to that, why isn't it selecting the 9th row, then? Why always the 4th, no matter what number goes in there?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (Excel 2016 x64). Is there more code that could be involved with this?

Comment: I agree, it certainly seems suspiciously coincidental that I have 4 columns that I'm trying to avoid, doesn't it? But I made a fresh sheet as a testbed when I started troubleshooting, in order to isolate it. In any event, my reference isn't changing between those two lines of code; taking a Range() of a Range object ought to give something that lies within the originating Range, right?

Comment: Got a repro. The problem is that your table doesn't start at row 1. Trying to find a work-around (other than deleting all rows above it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK finally got a repro. Your table doesn't start at row 1, that's why: the row offset matches the row number of your table's header row.

This is clearly a bug with the Excel object model. If you can't move your table so that the header row is in the worksheet's row 1 (in which case your code would work exactly as expected, as-is), then you need to work around it.

This seems to work:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Me.Range(rpt.Range.Address)
Me.Range(r.Cells(9), r.Cells(12)).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
```

Key being, you get the range off the sheet itsef, not relative to `rpt.HeaderRowRange`

Comment: Nice catch! I never would have thought of that in a million years.